# How to wait for the ready state of a newly opened window using selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, window-handles, webdriverwait

I am new to selenium. My application is very old application developed in 2004-2006 and every other action opens up a new window. I am using selenium web driver for internet explorer for writing the automated test cases.

I switch between opened windows using `driver.switchTo().window(windowname);`

however my test cases fail when my tests are run on other environments where the **response time**  of my application differs from time to time. due to which sometimes my test cases pass and they fail other times. Currently i am using `Thread.sleep(THRESHOLD)` , and i know its bad practice. I am aware of `WebDriverWait` and the three waits *Implicit, Explicit, Fluent*. But my problem is none of them wait indefinitely till i get a response. Every wait needs a threshold value till which it will check if the page is ready and if the response is not within the threshold then it will fail. Is there anyway where i can dynamically wait for the response, where sometimes the response will be immediate and sometimes it will be delayed. I all cases i should not enter any threshold value, and test cases should wait for the response irrespective of whatever the response time might be.

Comment: WebDriverWait accepts a long as a parameter. Why don't you use Long.MAX_VALUE - which is for all practical purposes infinite.

Answer (score 4):

As per your question *how to wait until i get a ready state of a opened window* it is worth to be mentioned that the *AUT (Application Under Test)* should have a benchmark on ideally how long it should take to *open a new window/tab*.

Now as @KDM indicated, the *WebDriverWait* constructors are:

- `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, java.time.Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepTimeOut)`
- `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds)`
- `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)`

In all the three constructors the *timeOutInSeconds* is of `long` type which have a **MAX** value of **9223372036854775807** which you can use too.

---

### Long.MAX_VALUE

In the following example the *WebDriver* instance i.e. *driver* is successfull casted with the **MAX_VALUE** value of `long` type:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.out.println("Long.MAX = " + Long.MAX_VALUE);
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  WebDriverWait wait_me = new WebDriverWait(driver, 9223372036854775807L);
  System.out.println("Application Opened");
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Long.MAX = 9223372036854775807
  Application Opened
  ```

---

### numberOfWindowsToBe()

Finally, when you use the tailor-made *Explicit Wait* to access *a newly opened window/tab* always use the [numberOfWindowsToBe()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe-int-) method from [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) Class and then collect the *windowHandles* as follows:

- Sample Code Block (Java):

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
  String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
  new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
  Set<String> allWindows_1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
  //Now you can initiate switching through windowHandles
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This code waits till the particular id is visible. And is initialized with 30 seconds before it throws an exception:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ifmail")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code snippet :

```
 public boolean softWaitForPageToLoad() {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 60).until(
                webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().matches("interactive|complete"));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here getDriver() function returns existing driver instance. Please replace it with your implementation.